# Why border radius color is lighter than the border color?

Tags: html

This the code which i am using in my page

```
    <ul class="tabs">
                <li style="border-left:1px solid #006699;">
                  <input type="radio" name="tab1" id="som" value="0"> 

                  <label for="som">Venta</label>


                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="tab1" id="som1" value="1">
                  <label for="som1">Aliquera</label>

                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://www.google.com">
                  <label for="tab3">YO Busco</label>
                  </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

### css

```
.tabs input[type=radio] {
          position: absolute;
          top: -9999px;
          left: -9999px;
      }
      .tabs {
        width: 95%;
        float: none;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
      .tabs li{
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #006699;
border-left:none;
        border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
        border-bottom:none;
        width:31%;
        background-color:#EDF6FA;
      }
      .tabs label {
          display: block;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
          color: #08C;

          cursor: pointer;
          position: relative;

          -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      }


      [id]:checked + label {
        background: #006699;
        color: #ffffff;

      }
```

I have to problems in this:

> 1.If we see the tabs carefully,we will see the border- radius color is lighter than the the border color.I don't know why its coming like
>   that.I want this to be same color as a border color.
>
> 2.When we click on on of the tab it changes the color.But if we observe it carefully we can see that there is a gap between
>   border-radius and background color.

Please any one help me in this.The js fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/ec8Hq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the sub-pixel rendering used. If the stroke would be thicker than one pixel, the color differences wouldn't be recognizable.

You also fade from blue to transparent for subsequent tabs. I replaced `border-left: none;` with `margin-left: -1px;` and the color difference is now even more subtle. You cannot do much about the rest (other than to increase the border-width).

Negative margin instead of missing left border example: http://jsfiddle.net/ec8Hq/2/

Also have a look at your example on a high-resolution screen (i.e. retina display) to see if that effect appears there too.

Sometimes you can also achieve smoother colored border if you use a box-shadow instead of a border.

**Update:**

Solution **A)** for the second problem is to set the border-radius definition on the outermost tab element only and use `overflow: hidden;` to force that radius for the child elements too.

A smarter approach **B)** would be to not style the list items at all and move any color definitions to the label elements. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ec8Hq/5/

Answer (score 0):

Change the border radius:`(10px to 7px)`

```
.tabs li{
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #006699;
        border-left:none;
        border-radius:10px 7px 0 0;
        border-bottom:none;
        width:31%;
        background-color:#EDF6FA;
      }
```